# Assert.assert.equal with multiple expected possibilities when one possibility will always be a null exception error

Tags: java, exception, logic, assert

I am having a Java issue that is driving me nuts.  I am trying to do an Assert of one object against one of 2 possible responses.

```
    Assert.assertEquals("Card status state does not match", true,
    statusResource.getActive().equals(response.path("status.active"))
        || statusResource.getActive().equals(response.path("cards[0].status.active")));
```

The plain English logic is as follows:
1) Assert if the active status found in the statusResource object is equal to either: 
a) the active status found in the response.path("status.active") or
b) the active status found in the response.path("cards[0].status.active")

and return the error message of "Card status state does not match" if the statusResource object does not match any of the 2 options.

The problem is that one of the response.path results for option 1 or 2 will throw an error of "`Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception.`" since the respective value is not present.

How do I perform my intended assert, when I know that one of the values will always results in a exception error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQvRo.png)

Comment: I would rather use a simple if-else loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem was BKAC (Between the keyboard and the chair)
Here is the solution:

```
      if (statusResource.getVerificationType().getMicro() != null) {

    assertTrue("Card verification Micro Type does not match",
        response.path("status.verificationType.micro").toString().equals("{}")
        || Integer.valueOf(statusResource.getVerificationType().getMicro().getAmount()
            .toString()).equals(response.path("status.verificationType.micro.amount")));
  }
```